# Problem: Calling C# Unmanged COM from C++ MFC

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, mfc, unmanaged

I used **UNMANAGED COM** to link a C# project to a MFC C++ Project using tlb-file. The program runs correctly in the main PC (where I compiled the codes). But when I run the program in another computer (with the same OS, i.e. Win 10), **runtime library error** occurs.

> C# Code

```csharp
namespace CSharpUnmanaged
{
public interface IGlobalInfo
{
    void multiPly();
    int Sum(int a, int b);
    double SuperPow(int x, int y);

}
public class GlobalInfo : IGlobalInfo
{
    public void multiPly()
    {
        int c = 4 * 5;
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("D:\\test.txt", c.ToString());
        Debug.WriteLine("MultiPly:" + c.ToString());
    }

    public int Sum(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
}
```

> C++ MFC Code

```c
#import "CSharpUnmanaged.tlb" named_guids raw_interfaces_only
int main(){
   HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(0);
   globalInfo.CreateInstance(__uuidof(CSharpUnmanaged::GlobalInfo));
   CoUninitialize();
   if (globalInfo == NULL) AfxMessageBox(L"NULL");
   globalInfo->multiPly();
}
```

> **I tried to track the error and I'm sure that the problem is related to the globalInfo which stays NULL during running the program.**

Comment: There something call as registration of com component with GUID. Did you registered in another machine?

Comment: why are you calling `CoUninitialize` before calling the method? Do you install MFC runtime on target computer? Do you install framework on target? do You register .NET library as COM on target?

Comment: @SantoshDhanawade How can I register that in another machine?

Comment: @Selvin .net framework and MFC runtime installed on target machine. Also the .Net library registered as COM.

Comment: target has no drive :D

Comment: @Selvin target has drive C and drive D

Comment: RegAsm.exe -tlb -codebase yourdll.dll

Comment: @SantoshDhanawade This script have to run on my PC or target PC?

Comment: target machine. New in com then should at least go through https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12673/Calling-Managed-NET-C-COM-Objects-from-Unmanaged-C once.

Comment: If you get an error, please add it to the question, unaltered. Plus, as was pointed out previously, you are uninitializing your thread while you still have open references to COM objects. That's going to cause bugs that have the annoying property of sometimes appearing to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks from @SantoshDhanawade...

On target machine this script have to run:

```
RegAsm.exe -tlb -codebase yourdll.dll
```

Note: Run Command prompt as Administrator.

This script creates a tlb file and must be replace with original tlb file.

Cheers...